# For which $r$ element of $(0,\infty$) $|x|^r \to 0$ if $x \to 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, continuity

For which $r$ element of $(0,\infty$) $|x|^r \to 0$ if $x \to 0$?

Somehow I have no idea how to solve the problem. I know that it's true for $r\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For all $r>0$**, one has
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}|x|^r=0,
$$ not only for $r\geq1$.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Would you mind pointing out a short proof for this. I was wondering when I tried something like a small number to the power of something like 0.00001, it still seems that it approaches 1 at some point, even before it reaches 0. Does it have something to do with |x|^r=exp(r*ln(x)) and since ln(x) -> -infinity for x->0.it grows faster than r ->0?

Comment: One may recall that if, as $x \to 0$, $\log(a(x)) \to -\infty$ then it means that $a(x) \to 0$. Applying it with $\log(|x|^r)=r\log(|x|) \to -\infty$ gives $|x|^r \to 0$, as $x \to 0$.